# Which norm is applied in Gram–Schmidt process?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am following [the wiki entery for Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) and it states that:

$e_1=\frac{u_1}{\|u_1\|}$

I can see they are using the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm in their example, But if I am applying this process in $\mathbb R^n$ should I use the $n$ -norm as in $\|\cdot\|_n$?

The question i am given is as follows:

Apply the gram-schmidt orthogonalization process on the following ${(1,2,3),(3,2,1),(2,3,1)}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ with the standard inner product.

Comment: You're using an inner product, so it had better be the norm associated with that. In the case of $\mathbb R^n$, it is probably the Euclidean norm.

Comment: The choice of norm is of course application-dependent, but as noted the usual choice is the $2$-norm. It's hard to tell since you didn't say anything about what you're using GS for.

Comment: @J. M. I have edited to include the question. Am i missing something?

Comment: In the absence of any other peculiar requirements, it's safe to go with the $2$-norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gram-schmidt concerns orthogonality. This means we must have an inner product around. This means you must also have an induced norm. You use that norm.

The induced norm is
$$||x||=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$$

Comment: What is an induced norm?

Comment: @oriya see edit.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\lbrace u_n \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ you can build an orthonormal system $S=\lbrace e_j \rbrace_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ with Gram-Schmidt: Let $e_1= u_1 / \left \|  u_1 \right \|_{n}$ and by recurrence define  $e_j = v_j / \left \|  v_j \right \|_{n}$ where $v_j = u_j - \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} (u_k, e_j)_n e_j$ for $j=2,3,...$ Note that the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induces the euclidean norm $\left \|  u \right \|_{n}:=\sqrt{(u,u)_n}$. Obviously you can get only orthogonal system, if not normalize.